# Java NPE while validating my own XML signature

Tags: java, xml, xml-signature

I have a signed XML request, which is rejected by the 3rd party because of invalid signature. Therefore, I wrote my own signature validation code to see what's wrong. However, I am getting NPE while validating the XML signature I just created. Here is what the XML looks like (I removed the irrelevant parts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelope xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="some_third_party.xsd">
    <header>...</header>
    <body>...</body>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="MySignature">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>AaV+ejxBF8GjJvIZA9Bonw81Z1Y=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#SignatureProperties">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>qcofYVnQ/n7sxKJPT5rG0+UYbjg=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>XXX</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>XXX</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
        <Object Id="SignatureProperties">
            <SignatureProperties xmlns="">
                <SignatureProperty Id="TimeStamp" Target="#MySignature">
                    <TimeStamp>
                        <Date>2017-03-01</Date>
                        <Time>09:06:36.779+01:00</Time>
                    </TimeStamp>
                </SignatureProperty>
            </SignatureProperties>
        </Object>
    </Signature>
</envelope>
```

When I try to validate this signature I am getting NPE on the commented line (so it actually happens when unmarshalling the signature, before the actual validation):

```
// Omitted: extract the X509 Certificate from the document
DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(cert.getPublicKey(), signature);
XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
XMLSignature xmlSignature;
try {
    // Null pointer exception here!
    xmlSignature = factory.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
} catch (MarshalException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

For completeness, here is how I create the signature:

```
try {
    XMLSignatureFactory xmlSignatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

    Reference ref = xmlSignatureFactory.newReference("",
            xmlSignatureFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(xmlSignatureFactory.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
            null,
            null);

    Reference signatureRef = xmlSignatureFactory.newReference("#SignatureProperties",
            xmlSignatureFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
            null,
            "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties",
            null);

    SignedInfo signedInfo = xmlSignatureFactory.newSignedInfo(xmlSignatureFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
            xmlSignatureFactory.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
            Arrays.asList(ref, signatureRef));

    XMLObject xmlObject = xmlSignatureFactory.newXMLObject(Collections.singletonList(new DOMStructure(timestamp)),
            "SignatureProperties", null, null);

    KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = xmlSignatureFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
    List<Object> x509Content = new ArrayList<>();
    x509Content.add(certificate);
    X509Data xd = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509Content);
    KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    XMLSignature xmlSignature = xmlSignatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo,
            Collections.singletonList(xmlObject), SIGNATURE_ID, null);
    DOMSignContext signContext = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, document.getDocumentElement());
    xmlSignature.sign(signContext);
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Edit: added the stacktrace to show where NPE is exactly thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLObject.<init>(DOMXMLObject.java:120)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.<init>(DOMXMLSignature.java:171)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshal(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:193)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:150)
```

Edit 2: I should also mention that both the SignedValue and X509Certificate content have whitespaces after creating the signature, which looks weird to me. E.g.

```
<X509Certificate>MIIG8DCCBdigAwIBAgIUJZSmBORuGuXyx48f04sNGHT+RhwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwWzELMAkG
    A1UEBhMCQ0gxEzARBgNVBAoTClBvc3QgQ0ggQUcxDTALBgNVBAsTBFBST0QxKDAmBgNVBAMTH1BL
    SSBTd2lzc1Bvc3QgTWFjaGluZSBBRVAgQ0EgRzMwHhcNMTcwMTI2MTIzMTQ0WhcNMjAwMTI2MTIz
    MTQ0WjCBsTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ0gxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkZSMSAwHgYDVQQKExdEaWUgU2Nod2VpemVy
    ...
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I now added the stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure `signature` is not null?

Comment: @RC. the whole <Signature> element looks good to me, except that there are whitespaces in both <SignatureValue> and <X509Certificate> content (see my second edit). I would expect these values to be printed in one line, without any whitespaces. I am not sure why this happens, that could be the problem.

Comment: I don't talk about your xml I'm talking about `signature` in `new DOMValidateContext(cert.getPublicKey(), signature);`

Comment: Ah my bad, no it's not null.

Comment: Maybe you could put a breakpoint in DOMXMLObject.java at line 120, figure out what's null here and move your way up from there to see what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem after some debugging. `DOMXMLObject` tries to get the local name of the *SignatureProperties* node, which returns null. I slightly modified how I create that element and it works fine now.

I am adding that piece of code in case it's useful for someone else later:

```
private Element createTimestamp(Document doc) {
    // Use createElementNS instead of createElement, otherwise you will get the aforementioned NPE
    Element signatureProperties = doc.createElementNS("", "SignatureProperties");
    Element signatureProperty = signatureProperties.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS("","SignatureProperty");
    signatureProperty.setAttribute("Target", "#" + SIGNATURE_ID);
    signatureProperty.setAttribute("Id", "TimeStamp");
    Element timeStamp = signatureProperty.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS("", "TimeStamp");

    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Element date = timeStamp.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS("", "Date");
    date.setTextContent(now.toLocalDate().toString());
    Element time = timeStamp.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS("", "Time");
    time.setTextContent(now.toLocalTime().toString() + now.getOffset().toString());

    timeStamp.appendChild(date);
    timeStamp.appendChild(time);
    signatureProperty.appendChild(timeStamp);
    signatureProperties.appendChild(signatureProperty);
    return signatureProperties;
}
```

Result of this method is then used in this line:

```
XMLObject xmlObject = xmlSignatureFactory.newXMLObject(Collections.singletonList(new DOMStructure(createTimestamp(doc))),
                "SignatureProperties", null, null);
```